# To access the index value of struts iterator in scriptlet array index

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

Using Struts2, I have a comma separated `String` of my images captions. While iterating the images to render on JSP I need to display caption along with specific images and could not get any specific tag to split caption `String` over delimiter and to access specific caption. I am trying the below code and don't know what to use in place of something to get the current iteration index in iterator.

```
<s:iterator value="images" status="incr">  
  <%= ((String)request.getAttribute("imageCaptionsString")).split(",")[something]%>
</s:iterator>
```

I know that using scriptlets and expression tags in JSP are not recommended, but I don't have any idea how to avoid it.

Comment: Yes you are right about scriptlets, but what do you mean by "expression tags"?

Comment: expression tags to evaluate and display the expressions <%= %>

Comment: For this purposes use OGNL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current iteration index is available via the `status` attribute of the `<s:iterator>` tag. In your case is `#incr.index`. If you want to display that index

```
<s:iterator value="images" status="incr"> 
  <s:property value="%{#incr.index}"/>
```

then scriplet could be changed to OGNL expression

```
<s:property value='#attr.imageCaptionsString.split(",")[%{#incr.index}]'/>
```

Comment: No Luck ! It is not displaying anything without any error. What is attr here ?

Comment: value="#attr.imageCaptionsString" is giving me the entire caption String but split method don't work. Any suggestion/idea??

Comment: I have made update to the expression, could you check if it works?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a lot and with the help of answer suggested by Mr. Roman C, I got the solution and keeping here for sake of any future needy user.

```
<s:iterator value="images" status="incrementer">
  <s:set var="cnt" value="%{#incrementer.index}" />
  <s:property value="#attr.imgCaptions.get(#cnt)"/>
</s:iterator>
```

This way I got the captions. Thanks to Mr. Roman C.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
<s:iterator value="imageCaptionsString.split(",")">  
    <s:property/>
</s:iterator>
```

If that doesn't work, then might be because it's a request attribute & hence, not available directly on valueStack, in which case you can use `#attr.imageCaptionsString` instead of plain `imageCaptionsString` in the iterator.