# How to get access struts value from jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, pagination, iterator

I am using pagination in my project. But my pagination index number is not properly set. Like:

**First page**

- John ...
- smith ...
- Doe ...

**Second page**

- New account ...
- New account2 ...
- New account 3 ...

I want the second page like this:

- New account ...
- New account 2 ...
- New account 3 ...

I use iterator to do this.

```
<s:if test="#request.userList.size > 0">
                <s:iterator value="#request.userList" var="user" status="status">
                    <tr>
                        <th><s:property value="#status.count" />
                        </th>
                        <td><s:property value="#user.userName" />
                        </td>
                        <td><s:property value="#user.userRole" />
                        </td>
                        <td><s:property value="#user.userEmail" />
                        </td>
                        <s:if test="#session.user.userRole.equalsIgnoreCase('admin')">
                            <td><a
                                href=<s:url value="/updateUser?id=%{#user.userId}" />>Edit</a>/
                                <a href=<s:url value="/deleteUser?id=%{#user.userId}" />>
                                    Delete</a>/ <a
                                href=<s:url value="/viewProfile?id=%{#user.userId}" />>
                                    View</a>
                            </td>
                        </s:if>
                    </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
```

I have to calculate index like :

```
index = #status.count + ((pageNumber-1) * pageSize);
```

How could I do this? I could not access value from struts (#status.count) in jsp code, pls.

Comment: How about using grid's? You can try the [Struts2 Jquery Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927173/grid-in-struts2-using-struts2-jquery-grid-plugin) for pagination, sort, add, edit, delete the record as well.

Comment: Did you try `#stat.count`?

Comment: use `status="stat"` in s:iterator  tag and use `#stat.count` as already said by @RomanC

Comment: It's not clear what you want: can you explain ? The second page you have and the second page you want are identical, except for the 2 not having a leading space ( `account 2` vs  `account2`)

Answer (score 0):

I would use index property of struts2 iterator:

```
%{#status.index}
```

You can find more information:

[To access the index value of struts iterator in scriptlet array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856296/to-access-the-index-value-of-struts-iterator-in-scriptlet-array-index)

https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html